# Encoding Debug Error When I Use VS 2017 on a XAML Sentence

Tags: c#, wpf, encoding, visual-studio-2017

I'm a developer Latim American Market, i'm been working for several years with VS2010 on C# With Framework 4.0, right now i'm migrating some of my project to Framework 4.7 but in may of my XAML i've been using ANSI character like á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ. This Works fine in VS2010 compiler without problems but when i open the same project in VS2017.

I got this error: 'Invalid character in the given encoding.

Line 51, position 76.' XML is not valid'
XAML Code have something like this:

```
<Label Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblDelDia" Content="Del Día" Style="{StaticResource LabelPrompt}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible,  Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

When i review the error is because this character "í", But the same code without change  compile fine with VS2010

Comment: Can't reproduce the error - works fine.

Comment: Works for me as well. Maybe you can try saving your xaml using File/Save as... and use the small arrow on the save button to choose *save with encoding* and making sure UTF8 is selected.

Comment: I found resolution to this error, i have to create from Cero all Project (.csproj ) Make this resolved this error

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem with russian cyrilic letters. WPF project, xaml windows, vs2019.

```
    <Button Grid.Row="2" x:Name="BtnClose" Content="Закрыть" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" Click="BtnClose_OnClick"/>
```

The compilator error was 'MC 3000', when i was compiling solution.

I was helped by opening the xaml file in programm notepad and changing the file encoding manually from ascii to utf-8.

Comment: Thanks. i solved the problem making the .csproj in VS2019, i add old files to a new project and app compiles  ok.

Comment: OMG you saved my day bro~